# Bundler is not compatible with Rubygems 2.0. Please upgrade to Bundler 1.3 or higher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, gem-bundler

I am deploying a Ruby on Rails application and part of the startup script that I have when provisioning a new box is `gem update --system`.

This happened to upgrade Rubygems to version 2.0. however, it looks like `bundler` is not compatible with this newer version of Rubygems.

```
Bundler is not compatible with Rubygems 2.0.
Please upgrade to Bundler 1.3 or higher.
```

Has anyone seen this or found a workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Updating to the prerelease of bundler fixed it.

```
gem install bundler --pre
```

Comment: That isn't working for me, installing "bundler --pre" hasn't solved the problem in my case. The app is using Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 2.0.0p0.

Comment: What version of Bundler are you using? What version of gem?

Comment: gem version 2.0.0 and bundler version 1.3.0

Comment: Took this as an opportunity to install Rails 4 with Ruby 2.0.0 and no go, getting the error:

$gem install rails --pre

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: rails requires activesupport (= 4.0.0.beta1), actionpack (= 4.0.0.beta1), activerecord (= 4.0.0.beta1), actionmailer (= 4.0.0.beta1), railties (= 4.0.0.beta1), sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0.rc3)

Comment: Wow, I'm sure glad I have my Ruby 1.9.3p374 install to fall back on. A word of warning to all:  DO NOT DO A "gem update --system", else you risk totally messing up your Ruby installation with no chance of recovery until this issue is solved. Wish I had the time to dig into it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and, since I was using RVM, I fixed it with the following command:

```
rvm rubygems 1.8.25
```

If you are not using RVM, you could just try the following:

```
rubygems 1.8.25
```

This should remove your Rubygems 2.0 and allow Bundler to work again.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/25/Rails-4-0-beta1/), in order to install prereleases using RubyGems 2.0 you must specify the version and disable `ri` and `rdoc`:

```
gem install rails --version=4.0.0.beta1 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

This works with bundler 1.3.0 too.